# MVVM Binding Selected item from one usercontrol to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have two usercontrols:
- the first contains a treeview
- the second contains some fields.

I want to update a Textbox in usercontrol2 with the selected treeviewitem-name from usercontrol1.

here is a part of my mainWindow.xaml...

```
<Grid> ...
    <View:UserControl1 Name="mycontrol1" .../>
    <View:UserControl2 Name="mycontrol2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mycontrol1.CategoryTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</Grid>
```

here is a part of my usercontrol1 (the "Category" is a List of category-objects):

```
<TreeView Name="CategoryTreeView" x:FieldModifier="public" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

here is a part of my usercontrol2:

```
<Grid>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

I found examples where all controls (treeview, textbox,...) are in one xaml-file but not if they are in two usercontrols.

maybe someone can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Viewmodel for both your views (UserControls) or you can use [event aggregation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591221/Simple-EventAggregator-in-WPF-PRISM)

Both ways work well

Comment: Is this a common way to use one viewmodel for two controls?

Comment: This or a [Mediator pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern)

Comment: isn't it possible to just use xaml-code with regular databinding instead of adding some extra c#-code? I thought maybe there is a way to bind the datacontext to the usercontrol1...

Comment: I dont think it is but when it is possible you dont want to because you dont want your views intertangled